# Laravel queues issues when I pass data from controller to jobs

Tags: laravel-5.6, laravel-queue

I'm having issue fixing the queue part for Laravel.

I have a contact form which works perfectly. I submit the form and a mail is being sent to me with the input details from the form.

But the issue is that if you do not use the Laravel Queues then the UX is lacking because of the waiting time before the mail is being sent and after getting the success message.

So now I want to implement the queuing part, but im not doing it right. Im still a noob at it...

Here is my controller

**KontaktformController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Jobs\SendEmailJob;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use App\Kontaktform;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Mail\SendEmailMailable;

class KontaktformController extends Controller
{

    public function create()
    {
        return view('kontakt');
    }


    public function store(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'mobile' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'subject' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required',
        ]);
        /*
          Add mail functionality here.*/

        $kontakt = new Kontaktform([
            'navn'  => $request['name'],
            'mobilnr' => $request['mobile'],
            'fastnetnr' => $request['landline'],
            'mail' => $request['email'],
            'emne' => $request['subject'],
            'beskrivelse' => $request['message']
        ]);
        $kontakt->save();

        //$user['email'] = 'test@test.com';

        $job = (new SendEmailJob($request['email']))
            ->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(3));

        dispatch($job);


    }
    }
```

**SendEmailJob.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Mail\SendEmailMailable;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $email = new SendEmailMailable('test@test.dk');
        Mail::to('admin@admin.dk')->send($email);

    }
}
```

**SendEmailMailable.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendEmailMailable extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;


    public $request;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('test@test.dk')->view('mail.kontaktform');
    }
}
```

**kontaktform.blad.php**

```
{{$request['email']}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I didnt pass data from mailable to my blade

```html
public function build()
    {
        return $this->view( 'mail.kontaktform' )->with( [
            'request' => $this->request,
        ] );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `kontaktform.blad.php` (which should be named `kontaktform.blade.php` btw), you expect the data to be an array because you try to fetch the index `['email']` though in your `SendEmailJob.php` in the method `handle()` you pass your email as a string.

So what you should change it to the following:

```php
$email = new SendEmailMailable(['email' => 'test@test.dk']);
```

**or do the following in the controller & in the job:**

Controller:

```php
$job = (new SendEmailJob($request))
        ->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(3));
```

Job:

```php
protected $request;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $mailable = new SendEmailMailable($this->request);
    Mail::to('admin@admin.dk')->send($mailable);

}
```

Now all data from the request is should be available in your blade template.

Comment: In the controller I insert new SendEmailJob($request->all()) and the data is being passed. But the JOB  still give me an issue. Do I have to change something?

Comment: Maybe try to do like this where you want to dispatch your job: ```php
ProcessAdminEmail::dispatch($request->all());
```

And be sure you have the artisan command `work:queue` running to actually process the jobs. You might want to read the documentation, it is REALLY helpful.  [https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues)