# Laravel 7- How to pass data(variable) from CONTROLLER to JOB to MAIL to VIEW?

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

I have seen this question asked a few times without anyone really answering it, or their method did not work. I am going to paste what I have thus far but I am still getting an error that the variable could not be found. The job queue works just fine but can not find the variable in the view. Below the code are the other resources that I have viewed that did not work.

ERROR MESSAGE- ErrorException: Undefined variable: newNeed in /Users/JandB/Desktop/myProject/storage/framework/views/dab250ddee8692f8f6a1fa3334aad4ba0eb81350.php:1

CONTROLLER

```
public function store(StoreNeedRequest $request)
{
    $users = User::where('team_id', '=', auth()->user()->team_id)->get();

    $newNeed = 4;

    foreach ($users as $user) { 
        SendNeedsEmailJob::dispatch($newNeed, $user);

        }

}
```

JOB

```
class SendNeedsEmailJob  implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $newNeed;
    protected $user;
    
 
    public function __construct($newNeed, $user)
    {
        $this->newNeed = $newNeed;
        $this->user = $user; 
    }

   
    public function handle()
    {
     
    Mail::to($this->user->email)
      ->send(new NeedsMail($this->newNeed));
        
            
    }
}
```

MAIL

```
class NeedsMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $newNeed;
   
 
    public function __construct($newNeed)
    {
        $this->newNeed = $newNeed;
        
    } 

   
    public function build()
    {
     
        return $this->markdown('emails.needs')->with('newNeed', $this->newNeed)->subject('New NEED');
    }
}
```

VIEW

```
{{$newNeed}}
```

Other Resources

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-job-not-passing-variable-to-end-view https://medium.com/@petehouston/passing-data-to-blade-template-from-queue-in-laravel-79130c598f01 [Laravel queues issues when I pass data from controller to jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55087211/laravel-queues-issues-when-i-pass-data-from-controller-to-jobs)

Comment: Do you get any errors ? What is outputted in the mail view?

Comment: What is the laravel version?

Comment: It might also be an idea to make sure your queue is running, I have found this is sometimes the issue

Comment: @IGP - Nothing is outputted in mail view. I edited and added error message and I am using Laravel 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have removed any previous jobs, and cleared any caching so that you aren't running an older version of `NeedsMail` without the `$newNeed` variable defined.

Comment: If this does turn out to be the issue it might be something to report since the with method does check if it is an array first and if not it will use it as a param 1 key and param 2 value. So the code "should" work from what I can see.

Comment: Going from the docs example, I wasn't sure that the `with` method would work when it's used alongside the `markdown` method, but looking at the `Mailable` class, it should. I can't see anything else wrong. Maybe OP should make sure that nothing has been cached and that queue workers have been restarted.

Comment: It might be laravel version in 8 it is like this, but I have not checked previous versions

Comment: I have cleared the cache, restarted the workers, and this still doesn't work.

Comment: Hey Jeffery, I have just tried your code locally with a fresh Laravel 7 install and I can't reproduce the error, so it doesn't appear to be a problem with the code you have written. You should make sure you have removed any previous jobs, as I can only think they may have been serialised with an older version `NeedsMail` without the `$newNeed` variable defined.

Comment: ok, thanks, I will try that @mikenewbuild

Comment: That was the issue, I needed to completely clear the entire application cache. That was causing the issues that I was having. You guys are awesome!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! :) I updated my answer to match your issue too.